# VAADIN -- Add TextField dynamical

Tags: java, vaadin

in a VAADIN Component a User should have the Option to insert one to N Answers to a Question.

Initial there should be one Textfield for the first Answer with a Button ("Add another Answer")

At Button Push there should added a new Textfield for the second Answer, and so on ...

My Question is, how can I realize the dynamical loading of a new Textfield at Button Push?

I Added a picture of how I imagine this Problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a click listener to the button which adds a text field to the layout. Basic Vaadin, no tricks.

If your code does not work, add it to your question.

Comment: But, if I add the Textbox via Listener, how can I read a value from it. I mean, how can I set an unique ID, to a generated Textbox?

Comment: When you create the text field, you have to remember it, say in a map that maps an id to a text field. This is not specific to Vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Textfield in a vertical Layout of its own, whenever the button is clicked, add a new Textfield to the vertical layout.

when its time to retrieve the answers, get the reference to the vertical layout and call getChildren(), this will return all the TextFields in the vertical layout.

something like this:

```
List<String> answers = verticalLaout.getChildren()
                                   .stream()
                                   .map(TextField::getValue)
                                   .collect(asList());
```